# Scaling large values down to display them with D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, epoch, graphite

I have some data that I have retrieved from the graphite API, but I'm having some trouble plotting the data due to the scale (large readings and epochs).

My data is in the format

```
var lineData = [
    {
        "target": "my.graphite.target", 
        "datapoints": [
                [1418819.0, 1408544820], 
                [1498919.0, 1408544880], 
                [1418719.0, 1408544940], 
                [1488819.0, 1408545000],
                [1478719.0, 1408545180]
            ]
    }
];
```

where the first point in the data point is the reading and the second is the time as an epoch.

To create my scales I am using

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .range([0, 400])
                        .domain(d3.extent(lineData[0].datapoints, function(d) { return d[1]; }));

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                        .range([0, 400])
                        .domain(d3.extent(lineData[0].datapoints, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
```

This produces the following svg.

```
<svg width="400" height="400">
    <path d="M-1563473334.4444444,
              7018085.291770574L-1563384334.4444444,
              7018085.591022445L-1563473445.5555556,
              7018085.890274314L-1563395556.6666667,
              7018086.189526185L-1563406778.888889,
              7018087.087281796" 
         stroke="blue" 
         stroke-width="2"
         fill="none"></path>
</svg>
```

My understanding is that the range and domain should scale the points from the data to the range, however this doesn't seem to be happening. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/5eyq6rk5/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xScale` and `yScale` are pointed at the wrong array indices when you define their domain. `xScale` shoudl use `d[0]` and `yScale` should use `d[1]`

```
var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 400])
    .domain(d3.extent(lineData[0].datapoints, function(d) { return d[0];}));

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 400])
    .domain(d3.extent(lineData[0].datapoints, function(d) { return d[1]; }));
```

Comment: yup, that's it. Cheers.